# How many message queues a windows app can have?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Is number of message queue(s) a Windows App can have is equal to threads in that app that create windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message queue is created only when thread creates a window. Before that a thread does not have any message queue. If creation of the queue will succeed or not depends on the amount of resources on the computer. The more RAM and free hard drive space you have, more treads and msg queues can be created. There is no any hardcoded limit on this.

In my experience starting more that a thousand threads most likely will create a problem even on a big box. But this still depends on the type of loaded drivers, number of network connections, etc.

Comment: So a Windows App can have as many as message queues - equal to the number of threads that create windows(if every thing goes fine) right?

Comment: Every thread that creates its own window (or shows a message box at least once), has its own message queue. At least MSDN is not explicitly giving other reasons for creating MQ for the thread.

Comment: A thread can have a message queue without creating any windows at all. A thread does not need a window to receive a message, for instance via `PostThreadMessage()`. A thread creates a message queue the first time a USER32.DLL function is called in that thread.

Comment: I do not think that `any function` in user23 will create MQ.